# How to Run Java program in SFTP Server

Tags: java, sftp

I have SFTP server and client is going to keep the CSV file in SFTP Server. Can I run/deploy my program in SFTP Server to parse the file and send the data to another system? I dont want to bring the data to another server and parse it.

My Question is "Can I run the java program from SFTP Server?"

Thanks

Comment: Your SFTP server is just a computer. You can run anything you want on it. If Andres’ answer isn’t enough for you, then you’ll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a Java program almost on any OS. So, yes.

However, you won't be able to execute it from an sftp client.

Comment: Thanks, My java program is ready but I did not see any SFTP server. So i wanted to know whether its possible or not.

Comment: Yeah I am not using SFTP client. I will get the access to SFTP Server itself. Its a windows Server and I need to run the code from that server.